# How to get a value from a JSON string?

Tags: python

I make an API get call and save the responses content. I can't show all the API content but here is the name value:

`"name":"TT REG – 2015 / Test"`

I create my JSON by doing a `json.loads(api_content)`. My JSON then has a value `[{'name': 'TT REG \u2015 / Test'}]` listed and I am trying to pull out the `'name'` value.

I am not able to upload the entire JSON

Is this possible with the `json[0].get('name')`? I don't get back any value but it checks out as a valid JSON file.

The `\u` is in there because the API call that grabs the content contains a `-` and the `\u` gets put in when I load the JSON.

**Answer**
I found out the issues was that the '-' was an ndash unicode character that some user had used. When running the `json.loads` command, it gave the equivalent of the unicode character.

To resolve this, I ran `json[0].get('name).encode('utf8)

Comment: Are you *deserializing* the JSON string? Can you provide a [mcve]

Comment: Can you show a bit more of the Json? I mean... `[{'name': 'TT REG \u2015 / Test'}]` is not a valid JSON per se... Is that within some quoting or something?

Comment: Show the *exact* value of `api_content` that you are passing to `json.loads`.

Comment: I found out the issues was that the '-' was an ndash unicode character that some user had used. When running the `json.loads` command, it gave the equivalent of the unicode character.

To resolve this, I ran `json[0].get('name).encode('utf8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to parse the JSON so you can access the name value, you can do the following

```
import json

string = unicode('[{"name": "TT REG \u2015"}]')
data = json.loads(string)

name = data[0]["name"]
```

Comment: @Robᵩ fixed the '

Comment: I get this error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 3251: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @user2769952 are you required to use python 2? its mostly deprecated now

Comment: Yes, we cannot change at this point

Comment: You are getting this error because python 2 cannot handle unicode very well, so it is likely that your file contains a unicode character which python cannot handle

Comment: Even Python 2.x handles Unicode fairly well (for *x* >= 6 or so at least) but the JSON decoder might be picky about what Unicode it accepts. Try doubling the backslash in `\u` maybe? And please [edit] your question to document the Python version requirement; 2.6 didn't have `json` out of the box so I'm guessing add the tag [tag:python-2.7] ...?

Comment: @tripleee, thanks for your comment. It helped me find the solution